# Nginx site can't be reached

Tags: nginx, centos6

I tried installing nginx with virtual hosting enabled with a single site currently hosted.

my nginx.conf

```
    user  nginxsite;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

#server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;

}
```

I assume that the `user nginxsite;` is the useradd created for the root directory ownership. default of that is just `nginx`.

my virtual.conf inside `/etc/nginx/conf.d/`

```
server {

listen 80;
#listen *:80;
server_name www.nginxsite.domain.com *.nginxsite.domain.com;
#access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log

 location / {
root /var/www/nginxsite.com/public_html/;
index index.html index.htm; }
}
```

The server name and ip has already been added in my hostfile
`XX.XX.XX.XX    www.nginxsite.domain.com`

I'm pretty sure the issue lies in my conf files but I can't seem to point out where.

Checked the logs but there's nothing.

Please help.

Thanks so much!

Comment: How did you try reach? I think the `location /` is unneeded (in your case), the `root` and the `index` directives can in `server` section. I think some error should appear in `error_log`.

Comment: It's not showing anything in the error logs `/var/log/nginx/error.log` it seems that it's not even reaching it. tried to do `telnet <server_ip> 80` and i can't connect. hope that makes sense.

Comment: Did you try it with or without `www.` prefix?

Comment: on the browser you mean? yes i did. and still doesn't work.

Comment: I think you should with `www`.

Comment: I'm at lost. Tried using the default directory `/usr/share/nginx/` in the `virtual.conf` and changed the `server_name` to `localhost` or my server IP, and used that localhost IP of the server on the browser still to no avail.

I'm gonna try reinstalling nginx and try to configure using the default webiste and will lset you know. Thank @uzsolt